# Can you use glyphicons on ASP classic pages?

Tags: html, asp-classic, glyphicons

Can you use glyphicons on ASP pages?

Comment: the question is why not ???

Comment: Yes. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glyphicons can be used in .asp file as the same as in .html file. So, if you want to use glyphicons then please use it with bootstrap in your project.

Glyphicons Halflings are not free and require licensing, however their creator has made them available for Bootstrap projects free of cost. For more details visit :

[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_glyphicons.htm)